# How can you style skype for business html messages while using the bot framework?

Tags: c#, html, css, botframework, skype-for-business

I've made a bot using the bot framework by microsoft, i know we can send html messages but css doesn't work. Html messages look really dull and  i want to apply some sort of styling to style tables/links.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has been addressed, but I noticed you mentioned you're using HTML tables.

I was able to successfully style tables in my bot by using inline CSS like this for example:

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">

<tr>
<td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; padding: 8px;">
<b>Column</b>
</td>

<td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; padding: 8px;">
<b>Column</b>
</td>

<td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; padding: 8px;">
<b>Column</b>
</td>

<td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; padding: 8px;">
<b>Column</b>
</td>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#84fd8c">
<td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; padding: 8px;">
<b>Column</b>
</td>

<td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; padding: 8px;">
<b>Column</b>
</td>

<td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; padding: 8px;">
<b>Column</b>
</td>

<td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; padding: 8px;">
<b>Column</b>
</td>

</tr>

</table>
```

I made a style using this technique in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and then used a string builder to construct the table with the styling I wanted in my bot code. Here is an example of how this type of table looks in Microsoft Teams:
[image]

Comment: The thing is i have to deploy my bot on skype for business, and apparently it does not support CSS.

Comment: I see. You may be able to style the text attribute within Cards (Hero & Thumbnail) by using HTML and some attributes then? Like changing [text color](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_font_color.asp) for instance

Comment: Skype for business doesn't support cards as well :( but thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have some documentation on how to achieve this:

[Rich Messages](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tsmatsuz/2016/08/31/microsoft-bot-framework-messages-howto-image-html-card-button-etc/)

It allows you to use the following:

1. Markdown
2. Attachments
3. Cards

And more! All fairly standard interactions and message formats across a bunch of channels (e.g. slack etc).

I really would recommend a quick search through MSFT's documentation on the bot framework next time, as then article wasn't terribly difficult to find.

Comment: Rich text/ cards are not allowed in skype for business, and apparently css does not work either.                                                        https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/overview#feature-support

Comment: @DanialAftab what a surprise that Microsoft's own product is behind the others when using *another* of Microsoft's products *facepalm*